# How to update WP post_meta products sale price with one query, if _sale_price exists update it, if not insert new row

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, price

In WordPress table wp_postmeta products data is stored like this:

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6677055 | 36828 | _product_version | 4.7.0 |  |
| 6677056 | 36828 | _price | 439.2 |  |
| 6677057 | 36828 | _wp_trash_meta_comments_status | a:0:{} |  |
| 6677058 | 36828 | _wp_desired_post_slug | notebook-black-spire-v-nitro-vn7-591g |  |
| 6677059 | 36828 | _wxr_import_has_attachment_refs | 1 |  |
| 6677060 | 36828 | _wp_page_template | default |  |
| 6677049 | 36828 | _virtual | no |  |
| 6677047 | 36828 | _backorders | no |  |
| 6677048 | 36828 | _sold_individually | yes |  |
| 6677053 | 36828 | _stock | NULL |  |
| 6677052 | 36828 | _download_expiry | -1 |  |
| 6677050 | 36828 | _downloadable | no |  |
| 6677043 | 36828 | _sale_price | 439.2 |  |
| 6677042 | 36828 | _regular_price | 1596 |  |

Sometimes products have a row `_sale_price` with `meta_value`=`SOME_NUMBER`

Values for sale price are changing daily and I want to make a MySQL query that will behave like this:

```
For post_id=36828 update meta_value WHERE meta_key="_sale_price"
IF meta_key="_sale_price" doesn't exist insert it.
```

I have tried doing it like this - updatin old value `439.2 -> 100`:

```
SELECT meta_value, REPLACE (meta_value,439.2,100) FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price";
```

but that didn't do anything, meaning that after I run this query I get as if it is successful and see this: https://dbfiddle.uk/t7W5AB9V (thank you @nbk)

but when I refresh my table I don't see a change in the row `meta_id=6677043`.

Do you have any suggestions or is the only proper way to search for existing entry and then update if it exists or insert if it doesn't?

Comment: to update you need a update statement ir you only  want so display it?

Comment: it is very unclear what you want to try it works, of you want to replace to value https://dbfiddle.uk/t7W5AB9V

Comment: @nbk After I run my query and refresh the table I don't see the change in the row with `meta_id=6677043`. I will update my question with this.

Comment: If you update/set the _sale_price, you need also to update _price…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports two forms of insert-or-replace: [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) and [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

But both of these statements don't know what constitutes a duplicate unless a primary key or unique key is defined in the table, such that when you insert a row, the value in the primary/unique key conflicts with another row.

In the case of the standard [`wp_postmeta` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta), there's a primary key on `meta_id`, but no other unique key. So if you insert a new row with the same `meta_key` of '_sale_price', it won't count as a duplicate. If the table had a unique key over `(post_id, meta_key)`, then it would only allow one row per post with a given value for `meta_key`, and inserting a second time with the same value would trigger the behavior for duplicates.

But if you define such a unique key, it would apply to *all* meta_key values, not just '_sale_price'. We don't know that there aren't other meta_keys for which it is normal to allow multiple rows.

So the only solution I can recommend is to do your update in two queries.

1. SELECT for the row with the '_sale_price' key for the respective post.
2. If no row is found (i.e. the result of the SELECT is empty), then INSERT a row.
3. Otherwise UPDATE the existing row.

This method has an unavoidable race condition. If two sessions are doing the same operation concurrently, they could both do their SELECT and think there is no row. Then both INSERT a row. The chances of this race condition may be low enough that you are willing to accept the risk.

Or you could add table-locking logic to prevent multiple sessions from doing the action at the same time.

Comment: thank you, I have come to the same conclusion since it seems that's how WP is functioning...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic approach

sample First for update (with row)

```
CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
  `meta_id` INTEGER primary key auto_increment,
    `post_id` INTEGER,
  `meta_key` VARCHAR(31),
  `meta_value` VARCHAR(37)
);

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta
  (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
VALUES
  ('6677055', '36828', '_product_version', '4.7.0'),
  ('6677056', '36828', '_price', '439.2'),
  ('6677057', '36828', '_wp_trash_meta_comments_status', 'a:0:{}'),
  ('6677058', '36828', '_wp_desired_post_slug', 'notebook-black-spire-v-nitro-vn7-591g'),
  ('6677059', '36828', '_wxr_import_has_attachment_refs', '1'),
  ('6677060', '36828', '_wp_page_template', 'default'),
  ('6677049', '36828', '_virtual', 'no'),
  ('6677047', '36828', '_backorders', 'no'),
  ('6677048', '36828', '_sold_individually', 'yes'),
  ('6677053', '36828', '_stock', NULL),
  ('6677052', '36828', '_download_expiry', '-1'),
  ('6677050', '36828', '_downloadable', 'no'),
  ('6677043', '36828', '_sale_price', '439.2'),
  ('6677042', '36828', '_regular_price', '1596');
```

> ```
> Records: 14  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT `meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`
  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
  WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price";
```

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6677043 | 36828 | _sale_price | 439.2 |

```
SELECT
if (exists(SELECT 1 from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ) 
, @sql := 'UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
  SET meta_value = 100
WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ',
@sql := 'INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (36828,"_sale_price",100) ');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

| if (exists(SELECT 1 from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ) , @sql := 'UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value = 100 WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ', @sql := 'INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( `post_id`, `meta_key`, `met |
| --- |
| UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value = 100 WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" |

> ```
> Statement prepared
> ```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT `meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`
  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
  WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price";
```

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6677043 | 36828 | _sale_price | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FqJtir-e)

Sample for insert (where the row is missing

```
CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
  `meta_id` INTEGER primary key auto_increment,
    `post_id` INTEGER,
  `meta_key` VARCHAR(31),
  `meta_value` VARCHAR(37)
);

INSERT INTO wp_postmeta
  (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
VALUES
  ('6677055', '36828', '_product_version', '4.7.0'),
  ('6677056', '36828', '_price', '439.2'),
  ('6677057', '36828', '_wp_trash_meta_comments_status', 'a:0:{}'),
  ('6677058', '36828', '_wp_desired_post_slug', 'notebook-black-spire-v-nitro-vn7-591g'),
  ('6677059', '36828', '_wxr_import_has_attachment_refs', '1'),
  ('6677060', '36828', '_wp_page_template', 'default'),
  ('6677049', '36828', '_virtual', 'no'),
  ('6677047', '36828', '_backorders', 'no'),
  ('6677048', '36828', '_sold_individually', 'yes'),
  ('6677053', '36828', '_stock', NULL),
  ('6677052', '36828', '_download_expiry', '-1'),
  ('6677050', '36828', '_downloadable', 'no'),
  ('6677042', '36828', '_regular_price', '1596');
```

> ```
> Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT `meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`
  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
  WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price";
```

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

```
SELECT
if (exists(SELECT 1 from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ) 
, @sql := 'UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
  SET meta_value = 100
WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ',
@sql := 'INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (36828,"_sale_price",100) ');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

| if (exists(SELECT 1 from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ) , @sql := 'UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value = 100 WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price" ', @sql := 'INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( `post_id`, `meta_key`, `met |
| --- |
| INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (36828,"_sale_price",100) |

> ```
> Statement prepared
> ```

```
SELECT `meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`
  FROM `wp_postmeta` 
  WHERE post_id=36828 and meta_key="_sale_price";
```

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6677061 | 36828 | _sale_price | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DQJJ0A7J)

more dynamic is when you make id post_id and the price variable

Comment: Thank you, but what if `meta_key=_sale_price` doesn't exist?

Comment: Thank you for a detailed solution. I am worried that on the shared hosting with over 10000 products this will too much for the server, although it seems as an interesting workaround :)

Comment: you can make in php a loop over all post_ids and use the id as variable in the query